# how do you count the number of digits in an int?

Tags: java

I have been working hard to try and figure out a way to count the number of 2's or whatever digit you want to figure out a way to count the number of 2's and print the amount of 2's in the int.

if i put in a random number like 3552342343
am i am looking for 3's i would want it to print 4 because their is 4 3's.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Your code as you've listed it won't compile, so we can't speculate on what the runtime error would be.  Please post a complete question and give details about the error you're receiving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use split to find all the matches

```
String number = "128";
String digit = "2";
// expensive but simple.
int matches = number.split(digit).length - 1;
```

Say you want to use a loop and something like contains.

```
// no objects
char digit = '2';
int count = 0;
for (int pos = number.indexOf(digit); pos >= 0; pos = number.indexOf(digit, pos + 1)
     count++;
```

This would be faster, however not so simple.

As @Kon suggests you could iterate over the characters

```
char digit = '2';
for (char ch : number.toCharArray()) // creates an object
    if (ch == digit)
        count++;
```

or

```
// no objects
char digit = '2';
for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++)
    if (number.charAt(i) == digit)
        count++;
```

String has some interesting runtime optimisations and I suspect the second method is fastest, though you would have to test it to check.

Comment: I love how lazy this approach is, but it's a bit overkill, right? Iterating over the characters of the String's `char[]` representation and looking for `'2'`, or any other integer, must be faster and easier to understand.

Comment: thank you this is exactly the answer i was asking for you.

Comment: What if the number is negative?

Comment: @nasukkin it's a string search, so it doesn't matter what other character are present.